# How to chain in javascript yet get value in between

Tags: javascript, chaining

ok weird title, I know. However the question is simple. In a class I want to be able to do these two things:

`invoice.getAmount(); // returns 1000`

and

`invoice.getAmount().asCurrency(); // returns $1000.00`

I can do either, just don't know how to get both to work.

What I have for now for the second idea:

```
getAmount() {
 this._temp = this.amount;
 return this;
}

asCurrency(){
  if(this._temp){
    return "$" + this._temp + ".00";
  }
}
```

That's an ugly copy of what I really have but the concept is represented...

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: you should add a prototype function asCurrency() to the Number Javascript Type

Comment: ... or alternatively return an object with a `.valueOf()` method that returns the plain numeric value and a `.asCurrency()` method that returns the formatted string, if you don't want to decorate the built-in prototype object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trick is to use the `valueOf()` method.

```
class Invoice {

  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  getAmount() {
    return {
      valueOf: _ => this.value,
      asCurrency: _ => '$' + this.value
    }
  }
}

const i = new Invoice(150);

console.log(i.getAmount() + 10); // 160
console.log(i.getAmount().asCurrency()); // '$150'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
function getAmount() {
   return 1000;
}

var result = getAmount().toLocaleString('en-EN', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is a great idea.

Comment: "How do I chain?" -- "Don't"??? Is that basically what you're saying? Because I don't see how this addresses the question.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts try this: `Number(1000).toLocaleString('en-EN', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I understand what the function does. I'm saying that's not quite as convenient as having an actual `asCurrency()` function, where the implementation is equivalent to that. For example, in my answer, I could swap out `'$' + this.value.toFixed(2)` with `this.value.toLocaleString('en-EN', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})` and it would address the question, but all you're doing is showing an implementation.

Comment: I was just pointing that no need to implement something new to get `asCurrency ()` because of `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`

Comment: Thanks, we tried that before, unfortunately we have custom currency displays... dont ask.. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can override a few built-ins ([`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) and [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)) on the [`Invoice.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) like so:

```js
function Invoice(amount) {
  this.amount = amount;
}

Invoice.prototype.toString =
Invoice.prototype.valueOf = function valueOf() {
  return this.value;
};

Invoice.prototype.getAmount = function getAmount() {
  this.value = this.amount;
  
  return this;
};

Invoice.prototype.asCurrency = function asCurrency() {
  this.value = '$' + this.value.toFixed(2);
  
  return this;
};

var invoice = new Invoice(1000);

console.log(Number(invoice.getAmount()));
console.log(String(invoice.getAmount().asCurrency()));

// or more subtly
console.log(invoice.getAmount() + 0);
console.log(invoice.getAmount().asCurrency() + '');
```

Or using ES6 [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Invoice {
  constructor(amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }
  
  toString() {
    return this.value;
  }
  
  valueOf() {
    return this.value;
  }
  
  getAmount() {
    this.value = this.amount;
    
    return this;
  }
  
  asCurrency() {
    this.value = '$' + this.value.toFixed(2);
    
    return this;
  }
}

var invoice = new Invoice(1000);

console.log(Number(invoice.getAmount()));
console.log(String(invoice.getAmount().asCurrency()));

// or more subtly
console.log(invoice.getAmount() + 0);
console.log(invoice.getAmount().asCurrency() + '');
```

Comment: That look simple and elegant enough. Let me try it and if it fits my requirements I'll mark you as the answer. Thanks

Comment: sorry but I ended up using @ankr solution. Yours required that I use Number/String on my returned value.

Comment: @RomainGonçalvès I probably should have pointed out, his solution requires that too, he just implicitly invokes `valueOf()` with `+ 10`

Comment: I like this answer. I think it is clearer and has more maintainability.

Answer (score -1):

Remember that `getAmount` is returning a number.

Thus, there is no way to chain `asCurrency` on the return value of `getAmount` (without using [`valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)) unless `asCurrency` exists on the `Number` prototype.

If you wanted to keep all this composed in your class without modifying the `Number` prototype, you need to either use `valueOf` (best solution), or make your return value of `getAmount` your class instance so that you can chain it with `asCurrency`.